# how to create json with two array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two json:
I want to create json with those two array;

```
 var __columns = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4"];
 var __rows = ["valueField1_1", "valueField2_1", "valueField3_1", "valueField4_1", "valueField1_2", "valueField2_2", "valueField3_2", "valueField4_2", "valueField1_3", "valueField2_3", "valueField3_3", "valueField4_3"];
```

The thing is that I wanna create something like this

```
var json = [{
  "Field1":"valueField1_1",
  "Field2":"valueField2_1",
  "Field3":"valueField3_1",
  "Field4":"valueField4_1"
},{
  "Field1":"valueField1_2",
  "Field2":"valueField2_2",
  "Field3":"valueField3_2",
  "Field4":"valueField4_2"
},{
  "Field1":"valueField1_3",
  "Field2":"valueField2_3",
  "Field3":"valueField3_3",
  "Field4":"valueField4_3"
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

ES6 solution using **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** and **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** methods.

```js
var __columns = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4"];
var __rows = ["valueField1_1", "valueField2_1", "valueField3_1", "valueField4_1", "valueField1_2", "valueField2_2", "valueField3_2", "valueField4_2", "valueField1_3", "valueField2_3", "valueField3_3", "valueField4_3"];

var res = Array.from({
  // generate array with particular size
  length: __rows.length / __columns.length
    // use map function to generate array element
}, (_, i) => __columns.reduce((obj, e, i1) => {
  // define object property based on the index values
  obj[e] = __rows[i * __columns.length + i1];
  return obj;
  // set empty object as initial argument
}, {}));


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function convertToJsonArr(__columns, __rows){
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
var len = __columns.length; 
var count = 0;

$.each(__rows , function(key, value){

  if(count >= len){
     count = 0;
     arr.push(obj);
     obj = {};
  }
obj[__columns[count++]] = value;

})

arr.push(obj);

return arr;

}
```

you can call like  convertToJsonArr(__columns, __rows);

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is using loops

```js
var __columns = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4"];
var __rows = ["valueField1_1", "valueField2_1", "valueField3_1", "valueField4_1", "valueField1_2", "valueField2_2", "valueField3_2", "valueField4_2", "valueField1_3", "valueField2_3", "valueField3_3", "valueField4_3"];

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < __rows.length; i = i + __columns.length){
   var tempObj = {};
   for(var j = 0; j < __columns.length; ++j){
       tempObj[__columns[j]] = __rows[i];
   }
   arr.push(tempObj);
}

console.log(arr);
```